How do I deal with my 500 error from my stripe integration?
I am trying to create a stripe session for my checkout in my Next.js project, and I have two issues. One is that for some reason, when I am sending body information in my fetch call, it does not seem to be arriving there. When I try to extract the information, such as amount, it is undefined.
The second, and bigger issue, is that for some reason I am getting a 500 error. I have followed the instructions and I have my environment variables set up but it does not seem to be working.
I am using the newer app router and this is the code in my api/checkout_session/route.ts file
import { stripe } from "@/lib/stripe";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

interface CheckoutSessionRequest extends NextApiRequest {
  body: {
    amount: number;
    success_url: string;
    cancel_url: string;
  };
}

export async function POST(req: CheckoutSessionRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const { amount, success_url, cancel_url } = req.body;
    try {
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
        shipping_address_collection: {
          allowed_countries: ["US"],
        },
        phone_number_collection: { enabled: true },
        line_items: [
          {
            price_data: {
              currency: "usd",
              product_data: {
                name: "Custom Amount",
              },
              unit_amount: 1499,
            },
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],
        mode: "payment",
        success_url,
        cancel_url,
      });

      res.status(200).json({ id: session.id });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: error });
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader("Allow", "POST");
    res.status(405).end("Method Not Allowed");
  }
}


and this is my CheckoutButton
"use client";

import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import React from "react";

const stripePromise = loadStripe(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY as string,
);

interface CheckoutButtonProps {
  amount: number;
}

const CheckoutButton: React.FC<CheckoutButtonProps> = ({ amount }) => {
  const handleCheckout = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/api/checkout_session", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        amount,
        success_url: window.location.origin + "/payment-success",
        cancel_url: window.location.origin + "/cancel",
      }),
    });

    const session = await response.json();
    const stripe = await stripePromise;
    if (stripe) {
      await stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
    }
  };

  return (
    <button role="link" onClick={handleCheckout}>
      Checkout
    </button>
  );
};

export default CheckoutButton;


The checkout button component is being called in a cart page.
I played with trying to extract the body in a few different ways. And if I console log req.body I get this output "ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }" which is weird because it doesn't even have amount or anything else in it that I can see.
As for the 500 error, I have tried a few different things I have seen online, but none have worked and this is currently the closest way to what the documentation seems to show.

Are you talking about a 500 error from your own system? (As opposed to one in a response you get from Strapi.) If so, certainly there should be more info in an error log somewhere.

const { amount, success_url, cancel_url } = req.body; - is that really supposed to correctly read the data, when you are sending JSON? Should you not be using req.json() or something in that case then?
